# Logical model in workbench

Tags: migration, mysql-workbench, physical-design, erwin

I have a physical data model of db in MySQL Workbench, how i can create an a logical model of this db(like in Allfusion data modeler(ERwin))? May be
Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

While the naming "physical model" seems to imply there would also be a way for a logical model, there isn't any. MySQL Workbench does not support logical models and tbh. this is the first request for that I saw in years.